# Memoize accepting Symbol('foo') as an argument

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement Memoize function that takes Symbol() as an argument. Is there a way to add Symbol('foo') as an argument?

```
let obj = {};
let counter = 1;
function foo() {
  counter += 1;
  return counter;
}

function memoize(fn) {
  const cache = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const stringifiedArgs = JSON.stringify(args);
    const result = (cache[stringifiedArgs] = !cache.hasOwnProperty(
      stringifiedArgs
    )
      ? fn(...args)
      : cache[stringifiedArgs]);
    return result;
  };
}

let id = Symbol('id');

const memoizedFoo = memoize(foo);
console.log(memoizedFoo(id)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(null)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(id)); // 2
console.log(memoizedFoo(null)); //2
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(5)); // 3
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(obj)); // 4
console.log(memoizedFoo(4)); // 5
```

Comment: it looks like the other question with the same flaws ... you could take a `Map`, which respects any type.

Comment: Why don't you want `null` to increase the counter the first time?

Comment: @NinaScholz it is a very good point , but I am not there yet. Ideally it should be solved with WeakMap + Map. That will be my second step.

Comment: @trincot Symbol() was recorded as [null] key. So when I call `null` the function does not execute it because it is already in the cache

Comment: OK, but then your *desired* output would be different from what you put in the comments of your last code block, right?

Comment: @trincot that is right ! `null` should increment on the first call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that a symbol has no JSON equivalent, and so `JSON.stringify` will return `null` for any Symbols in the arguments array.

One way to solve it is to apply `toString` to it:

```
const stringifiedArgs = JSON.stringify(
    args.map(arg => typeof arg === "symbol" ? arg.toString() : arg)
);
```

You could of course extend this to other types, or else use a `Map` which supports any type as its keys.